# Erro ao enviar dados de formulário Ionic + PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic

Estou tentando enviar dados de meu formulário, já todo validado para meu banco de dados em MySQL com PHP, mas me retorna o erro a seguir e não envia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso esta fazendo de errado? Preciso desta ajuda.

**Meu Controller:**

```
    (function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("nhaac").controller("serVovoCtrl", function($scope, Data, $ionicScrollDelegate){



         // ENVIAR DADOS            
    $scope.cadastroVovo = function(vovo) {
            console.log(vovo);
            Data.setData(vovo).success(function(data) {               
                console.log(data.data);
                console.log("imprimiu console data");
                alert(data);            
            }).error(function(data) {
                alert(data? data: "Não foi possivel cadastrar");
            });

        console.log("Vai imprimir o vovos");    
        console.log(vovo);

    };

    });
})();
```

**Meu Service:**

```
    (function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module("nhaac").value("Config", {

        getUrl: "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/put/"


    });

    angular.module("nhaac").service("Data", function($http, Config){


        //cadastro
        this.setData = function(dados){
         return $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: Config.getUrl + "rest-api.php",
                data: dados,
                headers : {
                                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                            }
            });
        };


    });
})();
```

**Minha View (Form):**

```
     <ion-view view-title="Tornar uma Vovó Cook" hide-nav-bar="false" >

            <ion-content delegate-handle="top" lazy-scroll >

                <h4>Cadastro de novos Cozinheiros</h4>   

            <form name="formCadastroVovo">

                <div class="list">

                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" >
                        <span class="input-label">Nome</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome" ng-model="vovo.nome" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.nome.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.nome.$dirty">Pereencha o campo nome corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                        <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email"  name="email" ng-model="vovo.email" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.email.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.email.$dirty">Pereencha o campo email corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                        <span class="input-label">CPF ou CNPJ</span>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ"  name="CPF" ng-model="vovo.CPF" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.CPF.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.CPF.$dirty">Pereencha o campo CPF ou CNPJ corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" >
                        <span class="input-label">Identidade</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Identidade" name="identidade" ng-model="vovo.identidade" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.identidade.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.identidade.$dirty">Pereencha o campo Identidade corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                        <span class="input-label">CEP</span>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="CEP"  name="cep" ng-model="vovo.cep" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.cep.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.cep.$dirty">Pereencha o campo CEP corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" >
                        <span class="input-label">Logradouro</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Endereço" name="logradourro" ng-model="vovo.logradourro" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.logradourro.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.logradourro.$dirty">Pereencha o campo Endereço corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                        <span class="input-label">Número</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Número"  name="numero" ng-model="vovo.numero" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.numero.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.numero.$dirty">Pereencha o campo Número corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                   <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" >
                        <span class="input-label">Complemento</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="complemento" name="complemento" ng-model="vovo.complemento">                    
                  </label>

                   <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" >
                        <span class="input-label">Bairro</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Bairro" name="bairro" ng-model="vovo.bairro" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.bairro.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.bairro.$dirty">Pereencha o campo Bairro corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" >
                        <span class="input-label">Cidade</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Cidade" name="cidade" ng-model="vovo.cidade" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.cidade.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.cidade.$dirty">Pereencha o campo Cidade corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" >
                        <span class="input-label">Estado</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Estado" name="estado" ng-model="vovo.estado" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.estado.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.estado.$dirty">Pereencha o campo Estado corretamente!</span>
                  </label>


                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" >
                        <span class="input-label">Responsável por Contato</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Responsável por Contato" name="responsavel_contato" ng-model="vovo.responsavel_contato" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.responsavel_contato.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.responsavel_contato.$dirty">Pereencha o campo Responsável corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                        <span class="input-label">Telefone Fixo</span>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Telefone Fixo" name="telefone_empresa" ng-model="vovo.telefone_empresa">
                  </label>

                   <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                        <span class="input-label">Celular de Contato</span>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Celular de Contato" name="celular" ng-model="vovo.celular" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.celular.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.celular.$dirty">Preencha o campo Celular corretamente!</span>
                  </label>


                  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                        <span class="input-label">Senha</span>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Senha"  name="senha" ng-model="vovo.senha" ng-required="true">
                        <span class="assertive" ng-show="formCadastroVovo.senha.$invalid && formCadastroVovo.senha.$dirty">Pereencha o campo senha corretamente!</span>
                  </label>

                </div>
            </form>

            <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-disabled="formCadastroVovo.$invalid" ng-click="cadastroVovo(vovo)">Enviar</button>

            </ion-content>

    </ion-view>
```

**Meu PHP:**

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
header("Content-Type: application/html; charset=UTF-8");

    //formulário
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $objData = json_decode($data);

    // TRANSFORMA OS DADOS

    $CPF = $objData->CPF;
    $bairro = $objData->bairro;
    $celular = $objData->celular;
    $cep = $objData->cep;
    $cidade = $objData->cidade;
    $email = $objData->email;
    $estado = $objData->estado;
    $identidade = $objData->identidade;
    $logradourro = $objData->logradourro;
    $nome = $objData->nome;
    $numero = $objData->numero;
    $responsavel_contato = $objData->responsavel_contato;
    $senha = $objData->senha;
    $telefone_empresa = $objData->telefone_empresa;


    // INSERE OS DADOS
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=ohostaqui;dbname=vovocooks_db", "vovocooks_db", "rain14570");

    if($db){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fornecedores VALUES (CPF, bairro, celular, cep, cidade, email, estado, identidade, logradourro, nome, numero, responsavel_contato, senha, telefone_empresa) VALUES ('".$CPF."', '".$bairro."', '".$celular."', '".$cep."', '".$cidade."', '".$email."', '".$estado."', '".$identidade."','".$logradourro."', '".$nome."', '".$numero."', '".$responsavel_contato."', '".$senha."','".$telefone_empresa."')";

        $query = $db->prepare($sql);

        $query ->execute();

        echo json_encode(array('message'=> ' Os dados foram inseridos com sucesso. Obrigado e bem vindo!' ));
    }else{
        echo json_decode(array('message'=> ' Não foi possivel iserir os dados! Tente novamente mais tarde!' ));
    };

?>
```

**A estrutura da tabela:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde está o código em PHP?

Comment: Achei que tinha postado, está ai... Obrigado.

Comment: Aproveitei e coloquei a estrutura da tabela.

Comment: O `undefined` me parece ser exatamente porque o objeto enviado é vazio (ou o atributo  `.data`). Além disso, parece que você guarda a senha direto no banco sem criptografia (sugiro um MD5()) ali no `INSERT`.

Comment: Oi @leonardopessoa sim, o data está vazio, mas lanço os objetos todos completos. Não estou sabendo resolver.

Comment: Então ele não dá erro? Só aparece como executado mas o valor não é inserido no banco. É isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo. @leonardopessoa

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que criar não só o model vovo, mas todos os seus elementos e quando enviar na requisição, + ou - assim:

$scope.vovo = {
  'nome' : '',
  etc etc...
}

Além disso é para usar Data.setData($scope.vovo), isso deve resolver...

Comment: Voltei só pra agradecer. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! :)))